# Using external Angular 4 component in my own component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to use jqWidgets Angular components in my project:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import 'jqwidgets-framework';
import { jqxTreeComponent } from "jqwidgets-framework/jqwidgets-ts/angular_jqxtree";

@Component({
    selector: 'tree-component',
    templateUrl: './tree.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./tree.component.css']
})
export class TreeComponent {
    @ViewChild('treeReference')
    private tree: jqxTreeComponent;
}
```

The problem is that inside my TreeComponent class I don't get type information for the jqxTreeComponent since it is trying to find it in this component (**Error message:** "*Could not find symbol '**jqxTreeComponent**' in external module **tree.component.ts**.*").

The import works and the external component is rendered on the site, only the type information is missing.

How can I get it or force it to search for it in the external component's .ts file?

Answer (score 0):

Add the external component to the `declarations` array in your AppModule.

Comment: I already did that, but I forgot to mention that the AppModule has the same kind of problem. The import works, but in the declarations it says: "Symbol 'jqxTreeComponent' cannot be properly resolved, probably it is located in inaccessible module."

Comment: Did you import the component in the AppModule file?

Comment: Yes I did, but I found the solution just now. It seems that ReSharper can't pick up the type information, as soon as I suspended it it works. Thanks for the help, I will try to configure ReSharper somehow.